# How to color each item per slide and revert back to black on other slides?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, itemize, nodes, animations

I want to highlight by color each item per slide so that it appears animated. That is to say I have two items under the label A.

[image]

Now I want to highlight the first item with the color red on slide 2. But the item is repeated below the first item (as shown in figure below) although `\onlide<3->` was provided in the MWE.

[image]

I want the second duplicate item to be invisible and the first item should revert back to black, and the second item ("Ut enim ...") should appear red on the slide 3. But again gets the second item gets repeated. ***How to color each item per slide and revert back to black on other slides?***

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Intro}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    bigcircle/.style={ % style for the circles
    text width=1.6cm, % diameter
    align=center, % center align
    line width=2mm, % thickness of border
    draw, % draw the border
    circle, % shape
    font=\sffamily\normal % font of the year
    },
    desc/.style 2 args={ % style for the list nodes
    % this style takes two mandatory arguments, as indicated by "2 args", so is used as
    % desc={first arg}{second arc}
    % the first arg is the color of the title/heading, the second is the title itself
    text width=5cm, % means the node will be kind of like a 4cm wide minipage, and if the
                  % text in the node becomes wider than that, it will wrap to the next line
    font=\sffamily\fontsize{6.5}{7}\selectfont\RaggedRight, % set the font in the list
    label={[#1,yshift=-1.5ex,font=\sffamily\normal]above:#2} % add the title as a label
    },
    node distance=10mm and 1mm % vertical and horizontal separation of nodes, when positioned with e.g. above=of othernode
    ]
    \onslide<1->
    {
      \node [bigcircle,red] (circ1) {A};
      \node [desc={red}{A},below=of circ1] (list1) {
      \begin{itemize}
        \setlength\itemsep{4pt} % reduce space between items in list
        \only<2> {\item \color{red}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}}
        \onslide<3-> {\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}
        \only<3> {\item \color{red}{Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}}
        \onslide<4-> {\item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}
      \end{itemize}
      };
    }
    \onslide<5->
    {     
      \node [bigcircle,orange,right=of list1] (circ2) {B};
      \node [desc={orange}{B},above=of circ2] (list2) {
      \begin{itemize}
        \setlength\itemsep{4pt}
        \only<6> {\item \color{orange}{Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.}}
        \onslide<7-> {\item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.}
        \only<7> {\item \color{orange}{\item  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}}
        \onslide<8-> {\item  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}}
      \end{itemize}
      };
    }
    % draw the line between circles
    \onslide<5->
    { 
      \draw [dashed,black!80] (circ1) -- (circ2);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get errors when I try to compile your code with `pdflatex`. And from the description it seems to me that you are looking for `\alert`.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems you may be looking for `alert`. If you want to animate the `tikzpicture` as well, I recommend the `overlay-beamer-styles` library.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{Intro}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    bigcircle/.style={ % style for the circles
    text width=1.6cm, % diameter
    align=center, % center align
    line width=2mm, % thickness of border
    draw, % draw the border
    circle, % shape
    font=\sffamily\normalsize % font of the year
    }]
      \node [bigcircle,red] (circ1) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
 \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
 \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
  ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]